# opecv template matching -> get exact location?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have opencv installed and working on my iphone (big thanks to this community). I'm doing template matching with it. It does find the object in the captured image. However, the exact location seems to be hard to tell.

Please take a look at the following video (18 seconds):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQnXNZMqpsU

As you can see in the video, it does find the template in the image. But when i move the camera a bit further away, then the found template is positioned somewhere inside that square. That way it's hard to tell the exact location of the found object.

The square that you see is basically the found x,y location of the template plus the width,height of the actual template image.

So basically my question is, is there a way to find the exact location of the found template image? Because currently it can be at any locastion inside that square. No real way to tell the exact location...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're not well-pleased with your template matching algorithm :)

Shortly, there are some ways to improve it, but I would recommend you to try something else. If your images are always as simple as in the video, you can use thresholding, contour finding, blob detection, etc. They are simple and fast.

For a more demanding environment, you may try feature matching. Look for SIFT, SURF, ORB, or other ways to describe your objects with features. Actually, ORB was specifically designed to be fast enough for the limited power of mobile phones.

Try this sample in the OCV samples/cpp/ folder 
matching_to_many_images.cpp

And check this detailed answer on how to use feature detectors;
[Detecting if an object from one image is in another image with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881133/detecting-if-an-object-from-one-image-is-in-another-image-with-opencv/7885168#7885168)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible features. That makes searching alot easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

Template matching (`cvMatchTemplate()`) is not invariant to scale and rotation. When you move the phone back, the image appears smaller, and the template "match" is just the place with the best match score, though it is not really a true match.
If you want scale and/or rotation invariance you will have to try non-template matching methods such as those using [2D-feature descriptors](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html).
Check out the [OpenCV samples for examples](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html) of how to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks, i thought the matching was scale/rotation invariant. But appearently not. Isn't there some build in functionality (not necessarily template matching) to find a certain object in an image? Like an orange surrounded with other fruits. Or a logo somewhere on a big poster. I couldn't really find specific functions for this in OpenCV, it was more about the theory behind scale/rotation invariant matching. Do you have any specific info about this for OpenCV?